# Javascript Countdown

Tags: javascript

I have searched the web but all the ones readily available are where you specificy a date and it counts down to that date. What I need is something which will simply count down from "27 minutes and 43 seconds" (in that format) all the way down to 0 from whenever they land on the page, anyone got any snippets available?

Comment: Googling for 'javascript countdown minutes seconds' will give you plenty of choice.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick. I'm bored and decided to do it myself instead of Googling. Just set the minutes and seconds at the top and change the call to countdown inside the onload to the id of the element you want it to update.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    var interval;
    var minutes = 1;
    var seconds = 5;
    window.onload = function() {
        countdown('countdown');
    }

    function countdown(element) {
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            var el = document.getElementById(element);
            if(seconds == 0) {
                if(minutes == 0) {
                    el.innerHTML = "countdown's over!";                    
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    return;
                } else {
                    minutes--;
                    seconds = 60;
                }
            }
            if(minutes > 0) {
                var minute_text = minutes + (minutes > 1 ? ' minutes' : ' minute');
            } else {
                var minute_text = '';
            }
            var second_text = seconds > 1 ? 'seconds' : 'second';
            el.innerHTML = minute_text + ' ' + seconds + ' ' + second_text + ' remaining';
            seconds--;
        }, 1000);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='countdown'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Upvoted, but it should be
    if(seconds == -1)
and
    seconds = 59

otherwise you have, for example, 5:01, 4:60, 4:59...

Answer (score 11):

I have made a simple countdown you can use.

It is generating the format:

> DAYS X, HOURS X, MINUTES X, SECONDS X

The JS:

```
countIt();

function countIt(){
    year = 2013;
    month = 05;
    day = 28;
    hours = 12;
    minutes = 00;
    seconds = 00;

    setTimeout(function(){
    endDate = new Date(year, (month - 1), day, hours, minutes, seconds, 00);
    thisDate  = new Date();
    thisDate  = new Date(thisDate.getFullYear(), thisDate.getMonth(), thisDate.getDate(), thisDate.getHours(), thisDate.getMinutes(), thisDate.getSeconds(), 00, 00);

    var daysLeft = parseInt((endDate-thisDate)/86400000);
    var hoursLeft = parseInt((endDate-thisDate)/3600000); 
    var minutsLeft = parseInt((endDate-thisDate)/60000);
    var secondsLeft = parseInt((endDate-thisDate)/1000);

    seconds = minutsLeft*60;
    seconds = secondsLeft-seconds;

    minutes = hoursLeft*60;
    minutes = minutsLeft-minutes;

    hours = daysLeft*24;
    hours = (hoursLeft-hours) < 0 ? 0 : hoursLeft-hours;

    days = daysLeft;

    startCount(days, hours, minutes,seconds);
    }, 1000);
}

function startCount(days, hours, minutes, seconds){
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML="DAYS "+days+", HOURS "+hours+", MINUTES "+minutes+", SECONDS: "+seconds;
    countIt();
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="counter"></div>
```

[Click here to see it live](http://jsfiddle.net/RUTVj/2/)

Comment: `thisDate.getDay()` should be `thisDate.getDate()` instead ;)

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for something like [this](http://javascript.internet.com/time-date/countdown-timer-2.html).

Answer (score 1):

um, why not just use this:

```
    <div id="countdown">countdown displayed here</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">                               
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //time to count down
            hoursToGo = 0;
            minutesToGo = 27;
            secondsToGo = 43;

            var startTime = new Date();              
            var endTime = new Date();
            endTime.setHours(
                startTime.getHours() + hoursToGo,
                startTime.getMinutes() + minutesToGo, 
                startTime.getSeconds() + secondsToGo, 
                startTime.getMilliseconds()
            );

            //function to update counter
            function update(){
                var currentTime = new Date();

                var remainingTime = new Date();
                remainingTime.setTime(endTime.getTime()-currentTime.getTime());

                $("#countdown").text(remainingTime.getHours()+":"+remainingTime.getMinutes()+":"+remainingTime.getSeconds());

                //call itself every second
                setTimeout(update,1000);
            }

            //start the countdown
            update();                
        });
    </script>
```

**EDIT**
As an added thought, you could implement this over multiple pages by passing the end time onto the next page as the value of a hidden form element. Or at least thats what i am going to do with it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[jCounter](http://devingredients.com/jcounter/) is a plugin that also accepts custom values to display any countdown you want

Answer (score 0):

I also made a count-down clock but with html5 canvas. 
Feel free to use it if you like it. (Run the code snipet below)

```js
(function() {
  /**
  * WlCounter pure JS class
  *
  * @class WlCounter
  * @Author: Wiktor Lis
  */
  var WlCounter = function(){
    // date settings - REMEMBER months in Date object are counted as an Array from 0! So months range is between 0 to 11. Other than that everything is just as you would expect it to be.
    this.setEventDate(new Date(2017, 03, 22, 22, 5, 0), 'Curently Unused'); // NOTE! months are represented from 0 to 11 in Date objects
    this.setEventEndDate(new Date(2019, 04, 03, 22, 9, 0), 'Curently Unused', 'Curently Unused'); // NOTE! months are represented from 0 to 11 in Date objects
    
    // CLOCK SETTINGS
    // clock size
    this.container = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      w: 150,
      h: 150
    };
    // ring stroke
    this.stroke = this.container.w / 10;
    // number font size
    this.numFontSize = this.container.w / 6 +'px';
    // label font size
    this.labelFontSize = this.container.w / 10 +'px';
    // colors
    this.colorRing = "hsla(355, 0%, 90%, 1)";
    this.colorActive = "hsla(355, 100%, 50%, 1)";
    this.colorTimedOut = "hsla(355, 0%, 50%, 0.3)";
    
    // OTHER
    // init objets
    this.curent = {};
    this.counter = {};
  }

  /**
  * This method creates canvas based on css id 
  *
  * @method createCanvas
  * @param {String} cssId of canvas DOM object
  */
  WlCounter.prototype.createCanvas = function(cssId){
    this.canvas = document.getElementById(cssId);
    this.canvas.setAttribute("width", this.container.w);
    this.canvas.setAttribute("height", this.container.h);
    this.c = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    return this.c
  }

  /**
  * Init all canvas objects and start counting down
  *
  * @method init
  */  
  WlCounter.prototype.init = function(){
    this.daysBox = this.createCanvas('canvas-d');
    this.hoursBox = this.createCanvas('canvas-h');
    this.minutesBox = this.createCanvas('canvas-m');
    this.secoundsBox = this.createCanvas('canvas-s');
    this.msBox = this.createCanvas('canvas-ms');
    this.startCounting();
    this.intervalClock();
  }

  /**
  * Assign curent time to class properities
  *
  * @method getTime
  */
  WlCounter.prototype.getTime = function() {
    this.curent.time = new Date();
    this.curent.days = this.curent.time.getDay();
    this.curent.hours = this.curent.time.getHours();
    this.curent.minutes = this.curent.time.getMinutes();
    this.curent.seconds = this.curent.time.getSeconds();
    this.curent.milliseconds = this.curent.time.getMilliseconds();
  }

  /**
  * Creates event start date  // and its message
  *
  * @method setEventDate
  * @param {Object Date} date - defines event start date
  * @param {String} messageBefore - curently unused
  */
  WlCounter.prototype.setEventDate = function(date, messageBefore) {
    this.eventStarts = date;
    this.messageBefore = messageBefore;
  }

  /**
  * Define event end date
  *
  * @method setEventEndDate
  * @param {Object Date} date 
  * @param {String} messageDuring 
  * @param {String} messageAfter
  */
  WlCounter.prototype.setEventEndDate = function(date, messageDuring, messageAfter) {
    this.eventEnds = date;
    this.messageDuring = messageDuring;
    this.messageAfter = messageAfter;
  }

  /**
  * Substract curent time from event date and define how many of days, hours, min, s, ms are left
  * If event starts counter finished -> change counter color to greenish (hsla(160, 100%, 38%, 1)) and count to events End time.
  *
  * @method startCounting
  */
  WlCounter.prototype.startCounting = function() {
    this.intervalToEvent = setInterval(function() {
      this.getTime();
      if (this.curent.time < this.eventStarts) {
        this.subject = this.eventStarts;
      } else if(this.curent.time < this.eventEnds) {
        // change colors
        this.colorActive = "hsla(160, 100%, 38%, 1)";
        this.subject = this.eventEnds;
      } else {
        this.stagnate();
        return;
      }
      
      var until = this.subject - this.curent.time;
      this.counter.ms = Math.floor(until % 1000);
      this.counter.sec = Math.floor(until / (1000) % 60);
      this.counter.min = Math.floor(until / (1000 * 60) % 60);
      this.counter.hours = Math.floor(until / (1000 * 60 * 60 ) % 24);
      this.counter.days = Math.floor(until / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      // console.log(this.counter);
      
    }.bind(this), 16.666);
  }

  /**
  * If counter will go pass the event start and end date, simply stagneta the clock assigning 0 to each clock
  *
  * @method stagnate
  */
  WlCounter.prototype.stagnate = function() {
      clearInterval(this.intervalToEvent);
      this.counter.ms = 0;
      this.counter.sec = 0;
      this.counter.min = 0;
      this.counter.hours = 0;
      this.counter.days = 0;
  }

  /**
  * Convert deg to radians
  *
  * @method degToRad
  * @param {Integer} deg
  */
  WlCounter.prototype.degToRad = function(deg) {
    radians = Math.PI / 180;
    return radians * deg;
  }
  
  /**
  * Draw the clock and sign it with the text from the @param2
  *
  * @method drawClock
  * @param {Object} ctx - canvas selection
  * @param {Array} timeUnit - example [this.counter.days, 365, 'D'] -> [0] counter number of days -> [1] max days for the clock to count down -> [2] Title that will be assign to the clock under the number
  */
  WlCounter.prototype.drawClock = function(ctx, timeUnit) {
      // background - gradient
      gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(this.container.w/2, this.container.h/2, 55, this.container.w/2, this.container.h/2,  this.container.w/2);
      gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(245,245,245, 0.1)');
      gradient.addColorStop(0, 'white');    
    
      // canvas rect
      // ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
      ctx.fillRect(0,0,this.container.w, this.container.h);
    
      // clock rim
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.strokeStyle = this.colorRing;
      ctx.lineWidth = this.container.w / 18;
      ctx.arc(this.container.w/2, this.container.h/2,this.container.h/2-this.stroke, this.degToRad(270), this.degToRad(0 - 90));
      ctx.stroke();
    
      // clock time
      ctx.beginPath();
      // ctx.shadowBlur = this.stroke-10;
      // ctx.shadowColor = "hsla(355, 100%, 0%, 0.2)";
      // ring countdown
      // ctx.lineCap = "round";
      ctx.strokeStyle = this.colorActive;
      if(timeUnit[0] == 0) ctx.shadowColor = ctx.strokeStyle = this.colorTimedOut;  // if time is 0 set color to gray
      ctx.lineWidth = this.stroke;
      // draw ring countdown
      ctx.arc(this.container.w/2, this.container.h/2,this.container.h/2-this.stroke, this.degToRad(270), this.degToRad(360 * timeUnit[0] / timeUnit[1] - 90));
    
      // text - number
      ctx.font = this.numFontSize+" Arial";
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
      ctx.fillStyle = this.colorActive;
      if(timeUnit[0] == 0) ctx.fillStyle = this.colorTimedOut;
      if(timeUnit[1] == 60000) timeUnit[0] = Math.round(timeUnit[0]/1000);
      ctx.fillText(timeUnit[0],this.container.w/2,this.container.h/2);
    
      // text - label
      ctx.font = this.labelFontSize+" Arial";
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
      ctx.fillText(timeUnit[2],this.container.w/2,this.container.h/2 + (this.container.w / 5));
      
      // draw!
      ctx.stroke();
  }

  /**
  * Set interval to draw clock around 60 frames per seckound (1s / 60  = 16.666)
  *
  * @method intervalClock
  */
  WlCounter.prototype.intervalClock = function() {
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
      // cl(this.counter.ms);
      this.drawClock(this.daysBox, [this.counter.days, 365, 'D']);
      this.drawClock(this.hoursBox, [this.counter.hours, 24, 'H']);
      this.drawClock(this.minutesBox, [this.counter.min, 60, 'M']);
      this.drawClock(this.secoundsBox, [this.counter.sec, 60, 'S']);
      this.drawClock(this.msBox, [this.counter.ms, 1000, 'ms']);
    }.bind(this), 16.666);
  }
  
  /* RUN WlCounter */
  var counter = new WlCounter();
  
  // FUTURE -> To Do
  // set event start and end
  // counter.setEventStart(foo);
  // counter.setEventEnd(foo);
  // counter.onEventStart(function(){
    // ...
  // });
  // counter.onEventEnd(function({
    // ...
  // });
  counter.init();
})();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
}

html, body {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#wrap, .text {
  width: 770px;
  margin: auto;
}

canvas {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 5px solid gray;
  height: 100%;
}

h1, p {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: left;
}

ul ol {
  padding-left: 20px;
  list-style-type: decimal;
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <h1>"WlCounter" pure JS class</h1>
</div>
<div id="wrap">
  <canvas id="canvas-d"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas-h"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas-m"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas-s"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas-ms"></canvas>
</div>
<div class="text">
  <p>JS WlCounter class counts-down to the event starting and ending date with color change on reaching the first one. After event start date is reached it changes the color to green and start count-down to events end date (if end date was specyfied and is more then curent time). So when event is ended, counter gets graied out and set 0</p>
</div>
```