# Simple SharePoint CEWP code for Countdown timer

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint-2010

I am building a virtual site for a project that is set to go live on 05/28/2014 and wanted to add a very simple Days Until countdown in a Content Editor Web Part. Unfortunately, I cant create any custom WebParts or use JQuery. I am stuck using basic JavaScript or HTML that does not access any external sites (they have very strict security). I am hoping someone might be able to help me create this as I am unable to find anything that fits via Google. An example of what I am hoping the end result will look like is below:

**Days Until Launch:
249 Days 16 Hours 45 Minutes**

I appreciate anyones help on this and want to say Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com).
dont think it requires jquery.

example here,
[Countdown timer using Moment js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129157/countdown-timer-using-moment-js)

or plain js
[Javascript Countdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532553/javascript-countdown)